# How do I negate falling damage in Starbound?

Tags: starbound

I want to build a hellevator (to borrow a word from Terraria).

What do I put at the bottom (or throughout the shaft) to make it so I do not die at the bottom?

Are there generic solutions to prevent fall damage for everyday falls I might take while cave exploring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way would be to use a tech power.

Both the Pulse Jump and the Energy Dash will reset the distance you have fallen. You would have to figure out when to safely activate them (this can also stop your fall at any time).

The other starting tech might be able to stop your fall, but I don't use it so I can't easily tell you (can't do the research either ATM).

A massive amount of water could also stop the fall, but getting the water to an area that you need it to be could be time consuming.

I would recommend the first option, and place some specific identifiers to show when you should activate the second jump or dash.

Extra Info: The Dash can be used over and over (if you have the energy to do it), but the double jump can only be used once (resets on touching ground), but it does not use any energy.

Comment: I know in terraria only 3 cubes of water were needed to negate any fall, and that was fairly easy to build into the bottom of a shaft. Do you have any information about exactly how much water I would need in Starbound?

Comment: While I was exploring, I took damage when I had fallen down to the bottom of a 10-15 block deep pool, so you will need much more water than in Terraria. I will try to do some research on it when I get home. But I would reccomend getting the Energy Dash or Pulse Jump. You can use it whenever, and it resets how far you have fallen.

Comment: Note, in my previous comment, I had fallen a considerable distance. But, seeing that you are making a Hellevator, it would not change anything.

Comment: Bouncy can also help, but needs enough space to deploy (I think 5 units will work, maybe 6).

Comment: The Matter Manipulator can be used to pick up and drop liquids, so creating a water pit shouldn't be too much of a problem now. Using a more viscose liquid like oil might also help. The big problem with a hellevator is not so much the getting down part, but getting back up from the bottom, since Starbound doesn't have Terraria's Magic Mirror

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can make elevators.

You'll need to upgrade your MM 3 times though (to get the ability to wire things up). A bit more advanced than water at the bottom but has the advantage of going up and down.

Answer (score 1):

Another way I found, in vanilla, is if you find a hammer with the ground slam ability it negates all fall damage entirely.

Answer (score 0):

the best way I can think of is if you use the aqua ball and wall jump tech
the aqua ball floats on water so with it, you require much less water to put at the bottom, and with the wall jump, you use it to get back up